# Generating Unity AR without target

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I've been looking into AR recently because I decided I should use it for my Android app and I found about Unity and Vuforia, which is probably the simplest way to implement AR. I've never before used Unity so I'm a complete beginner to it.

I've followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvSrZqP0elQ and it's working on my phone.

Vuforia uses marker, which I don't want. I would like for it to render AR image on the ground. More accurately said, I would need it rendered so that it is vertical to your body and horizontal to the floor.

Is there a way to do this in Unity with Vuforia? It would be great if I got any kind of help, for example link to useful resource or documentation, explanation or even example. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia does not provide markerless. They hqve smart terrain but seems to be oriente for games and has not been updated for years.

There are some SDK available like Wikitude, but they provide it as beta.

http://www.wikitude.com/blog-wikitude-3d-tracking-beta/

I think ARToolkit does something similar called Natural Feature tracking (NFT).

http://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training%3Amarker_nft_fiducial_markers

What you may look for is SLAM but beware that the technology is not yet mature.

There is Kudan but it also has limitations as it seems to rely on hardware. Gyro for rotation so some Android device won't do.

Comment: So which out of these would you suggest for me to use? I'm looking for something simple to use as I'm using it for only this app. Also, I'd need only a 2d image rendered, so maybe that can make it simpler too. Thank you for your answer. Also I don't know if you misunderstood my question, I don't need it to track for the floor, I just need it to render the image horizontal to the floor.

Comment: I would give a try to ARToolkit, I think it is open source. The others require license.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Here are some additional information. NFT still uses a picture as marker. But you can use any picture your want. So it still has to be trained beforehand and inserted into the system.