# Detect the floor/ground plane using Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

Hi I am a newbie to unity and vuforia, I am working on a project based on augmented reality. I wanted to detect the floor as a part of my project. However if I upload an image of the floor to the "Target Manager" in vuforia it it will detect very few feature making it harder to recognize the floor when applied the specific image to the "Image target".

My question is there any other way to recognize the floor/ground plane other than using the option "Image target"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into smart terrain feature?

Comment: i did tried that, but I don't understand how to add the image to the terrain, so i did a "plane" 3D object and add the image as a material. But when i play it and go to the game window it didn't show anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Unity AR without target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701973/generating-unity-ar-without-target)